# Burnside Theorems …

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have read that Burnside's theorem implies that a group with order $p^aq^b$ cannot be simple.

Well  how can I prove that: From  Burnside's conjugation theorem (If G has a conjugacy class whose order is divisible  nontrivial power of a prime, then G is not simple) deduce the Burside solubility theorem, i.e., for p and q primes, every group of order $p^aq^b$ is solvable.

Proof.

I proceed by induction on $a+b$. If $a+b ≤ 1$ then G is cyclic of prime order, hence abelian, and therefore solvable since its commutator subgroup is trivial. Now if G is of order $p^aq^b$ then, by Burnside’s conjugation theorem, there is a normal subgroup H of G. By the inductive hypothesis, both H and G/H are solvable since they are groups whose order is of the form $p^a′q^b′$ where $a′ + b′ < a + b$, so there are abelian normal towers
and
$H =A_0 ≥A_1 ≥···≥A_s ={1}$ $G/H =B_0 ≥B_1 ≥···≥B_t ={1}$.

By the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem the $B_i$ correspond to subgroups $C_i$ of G containing H such that $C_i/H = B_i$ for each i. It is easy to see that $C_i+1$ is normal in $C_i$ for each i since $B_i+1$ is normal in $B_i$, and the Second Isomorprism Theorem asserts that $C_i/C_i+1 ∼= (C_i/H)/(C_i+1/H) ∼= B_i/B_i+1$ for each i, so each quotient $C_i/C_i+1$ is abelian. Finally, $B_t = {1}$ corresponds to $C_t = H$, so we have that $C_t/A_0 = {1}$ is abelian. Therefore
$G=C_0 ≥C_1 ≥···≥C_t ≥A_0 ≥A_1 ≥···≥A_s ={1}$ is an abelian normal tower for G, and G is solvable.

Is it correct?
Thanks for you help and time.

Comment: Which Burnside theorem have you been told implies this? The one that comes to mind is the one that states precisely what you say it implies.

Comment: Ok, i edited  for more clarity

Comment: What do you mean by divisible between a nontrivial power of a prime?

Comment: So an immediate deduction is that a simple group of this form has all its conjugacy classes of order $1$, $p$ or $q$ - if I have read your edit right. And there is only one conjugacy class of order $1$ (the centre is a normal subgroup)

Comment: and then is solvable? i do not understand very well

Comment: Do you mean that if the size of some conjugacy class is $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and some $n\geq 2$ then the group is not simple?

Comment: If G has a conjugacy class whose order is divisible to a power of a prime nontrivial, then G is not simple

Comment: What do you mean by nontrivial here? And no, that statement is not correct. The divisible has to be replaced by "equal to".

Comment: If G has a conjugacy class of size $p^n$ for a prime p, then G is not simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the following:

**THEOREM**: If $G$ has a conjugacy class of size $p^\alpha$ for a prime $p$, then $G$ is not simple.

Then Burnside's theorem is easy: take a section of the composition series of a group $G$ - with $|G|=p^aq^b$ - and if this section is not cyclic, then look at the conjugacy class of a central element inside a Sylow subgroup.

**MORE DETAILS**: If a section $H$ of the composition series is not cyclic, it has order divisible by both $p$ and $q$; let's say it has order $p^nq^m$.  Then the Sylow $p$-subgroup has a non-trivial center, with an element $x$ in it.  Since $|C(x)|=p^nq^k$ for some $k < m$ (why?), the conjugacy class of $x$ has size $[H:C(x)]=q^{m-k}$, and you can apply the theorem above to reach a contradiction.

Comment: what is the meaning of section? can you be more specific please

Comment: @Knight: It is $H_{i+1}/H_i$, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#For_groups

Comment: @Steve D can you see the answer please

Answer (score 0):

If i take you comment  @Steve D the if i proceed by induction on $a+b$. If $a+b ≤ 1$ then G is cyclic of prime order, hence abelian, and therefore solvable since its commutator subgroup is trivial. Now if G is of order $p^aq^b$ then, by Burnside’s conjugation, there is a normal subgroup H of G. By the inductive hypothesis, both H and G/H are solvable since they are groups of order of the form $p^a′q^b′$ where $a′ + b′ < a + b$, so there are abelian normal towers
and
$H =A_0 ≥A_1 ≥···≥A_s ={1}$ $G/H =B_0 ≥B_1 ≥···≥B_t ={1}$.

By the Lattice Isomorphism Theorem the $B_i$ correspond to subgroups $C_i$ of G containing H such that $C_i/H = B_i$ for each i. It is easy to see that $C_i+1$ is normal in $C_i$ for each i since $B_i+1$ is normal in $B_i$, and the Second Isomorprism Theorem asserts that $C_i/C_i+1 ∼= (C_i/H)/(C_i+1/H) ∼= B_i/B_i+1$ for each i, so each quotient $C_i/C_i+1$ is abelian. Finally, $B_t = {1}$ corresponds to $C_t = H$, so we have that $C_t/A_0 = {1}$ is abelian. Therefore
$G=C_0 ≥C_1 ≥···≥C_t ≥A_0 ≥A_1 ≥···≥A_s ={1}$ is an abelian normal tower for G, and G is solvable.

Is it correct?

Comment: The part of this exercise that is supposed to be challenging is getting the existence of the non-trivial proper normal subgroup from the conjugation theorem. The fact about solvability is supposed to be "standard".

Comment: You are making this very very complicated.

Comment: Also you are making lots of mistakes: "Burnside's conjugation" does not immediately give you a normal subgroup.

Comment: But this is a consequence of If G is a group of order $p^aq^b$, where p and q are distinct primes and a and b are nonnegative integers with a + b ≥2 then G is not simple.

Comment: What are you talking about? That is the exact statement of the theorem you're trying to prove!

Comment: No i´m trying to prove that for p and q primes, every group of order $p^aq^b$ is solvable.

Comment: Proving it's not simple is the whole point! A silly induction gives you solvability.  I think you are very confused about all of this.  Showing the existence of that normal subgroup is the crux of the entire proof, and you wave it away in one sentence!

Comment: I agree with @SteveD here. It seems like you would benefit from reading more about solvable groups before trying to do this exercise. It is a standard induction argument to show that if $P$ is a property that is inherited by subgroups and quotients and such that no non-abelian finite groups exist which satisfy $P$, then any finite group satisfying $P$ is solvable.